# $U(n)$ and $U(1)\times SU(n)$ are not isomorphic Lie groups

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups

I am reading John Lee and on the chapter about group actions there is a problem that asks me to show that $U(n)$ and $U(1)\times SU(n)$ are not isomorphic Lie groups by showing that they don't have isomorphic centers. However, I can't see a clear way to compute their centers. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Shur's Lemma to show the center of $U(n)$ is the set of all scalar matrices $\lambda I$ where $\lambda\in U(1)$ which is isomorphic to $S^1$ (i.e. circle group). The center of $SU(n)$ is generated by the $n$-th root of unity hence the center is $\mathbb{Z}_n$. The result follows.

Comment: Okay, that tool seems pretty powerful.However, I was not aware of this lemma before, are there any other more primary ways to tackle it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, maybe I will go check out the proof. Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  By the short exact sequence $1\to SU(n)\to U(n)\to U(1)\to 1$, we have $U(n)/SU(n)\cong U(1)$, and by the fact that $U(1)$ is the center of $U(n)$, we have $U(n)/U(1)\cong SU(n)$, but $U(n)$ is not isomorphic to $U(1)\times SU(n)$, I'm still quite confused.

Comment: @YilongZhang Not every short exact sequence splits, so the middle group is not a direct product in general of the other two groups. You wanted to ask me here, or perhaps someone else ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think I get the point now, thank. I intended to ask you since you are active in Stackexchange.